# Xcode 9 Localization Not Working?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, swift4, xcode9

I have had localization in my app for Danish for a while and when I updated Xcode 9 and ran it in the simulator, everything started to show up in Danish... I have no idea why?

I made sure all my settings were in English and set to the United States but everything appeared in Danish when I ran the app in the simulator. Does anyone know anything about this? Maybe just a beta bug? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Matusalem suggested (setting the language to English or System Language), also make sure that your development region is English, not Danish, in your application's Info.plist.

If this continues please file it with the bug reporter, and also include the result of a print or NSLog of `NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments` added to your app.

Comment: managed to find the issue. apparently for localization, English is disabled by default now and the other languages were enabled, so on simulator it would display a different language. but still confused on why it was in english on my phone

Answer (score 0):

Edit your scheme and make sure "Application Language" is set to "System Language" in the options for "Run".

Comment: Confused on where to go? Where do I find the Application Language setting?